# Ora2pg export schema problems

Tags: oracle, postgresql, perl, migration, ora2pg

I try to migrate from Oracle to PostgreSQL with `ora2pg` on Windows.
When the migration template generated,I try to run `export_schema` script in `perl`.
But .sh-expansion not supported.
Change expansion to `.pl` and run this script leads to errors.

How correctly run and force this script works on Windows?
Maybe somebody already decided this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: simply get cygwin

Comment: It may depend on the version of Windows but I would expect that there are ports of bash available for Windows besides Cygwin.